# How do I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2n-1} - \frac{n+2}{2n+3}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2n-1} - \frac{n+2}{2n+3}$$

I've tried combining the sum, telescoping series and even trying to make an Nth partial sum but nothing seems to budge. I'm not sure where to go...

Comment: Can you write out what happened when you did the telescoping sum?

Comment: Be careful with the answers of  "no lemon no melon", "Brian M. Scott" and "RobertTheTutor". They forgot that to calculate a telescoping sum you need to check that the "remainder" tends to $0$, but in this case it tends to $-1$.

Comment: @jjagmath How do you check that the remainder tends to 0 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that
$$\frac{n}{2n-1}-\frac{n+2}{2n+3}=\frac{2n^2+3n-(n+2)(2n-1)}{(2n-1)(2n+3)}$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{2}{(2n-1)(2n+3)}$$
*Now* use partial fractions to form a telescoping series.

---

I hope that helps. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 8):

We have \begin{align}
&\sum _{n=1}^m \left(\frac{n}{2 n-1}-\frac{n+2}{2 (n+2)-1}\right)=\sum _{n=1}^m \frac{n}{2 n-1}-\sum _{n=1}^m \frac{n+2}{2 (n+2)-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{n}{2 n-1}-\sum _{n=3}^{m+2} \frac{n}{2 n-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\cdot 1-1}+\frac{2}{2\cdot 2-1}+\sum _{n=3}^m \frac{n}{2 n-1}-\sum
   _{n=3}^m \frac{n}{2 n-1}-\frac{m+1}{2 (m+1)-1}-\frac{m+2}{2 (m+2)-1}\\
&=1+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{m+1}{2 (m+1)-1}-\frac{m+2}{2 (m+2)-1}\end{align}

Taking the limit when $m \to \infty$ we have
\begin{align}
&\sum _{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{2 n-1}-\frac{n+2}{2 (n+2)-1}\right) \\&= \lim_{m\to\infty}\left( 1+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{m+1}{2 (m+1)-1}-\frac{m+2}{2 (m+2)-1}\right)\\
 &= 1+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{3}\end{align}

The others answer don't take into account that the "remainder" terms after "telescoping" doesn't tends to $0$.

Comment: This is the only correct answer so far.

Comment: The analysis of @A-Level Student is also correct and results in the correct answer.

Comment: @RobertShore But "A-Level Student" didn't finish his proof, so there's no way to know if he had made the same mistake. He upvoted the incorrect answer of "Brian M. Scott", so...

Comment: Well, you need to try his method and find the partial fractions. I've checked and it does give $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: A-Level Student's answer helped me get to the solution but this was also very insightful thank you!

Comment: @jjagmath it wouldn't have been possible to make the mistake with my answer, as the 'remainder' does tend to $0$, but you're correct in saying that I overlooked the mistake in a couple of the other posts. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Writing out the first terms explicitly, it is already telescoping, albeit a bit staggered:
$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{4}{7}+\frac{3}{5}-\frac{5}{9}+\frac{4}{7}-\frac{6}{11} + ...$$
It looks like $1+\frac{2}{3} = \frac{5}{3}$ is the answer.
I suspect that if one of the terms is index shifted by one, the relation would be much more obvious:
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{3}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+2}{2n+3} = $$
$$\frac{5}{3}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+2-2}{2(k+2)+3} -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+2}{2n+3} $$
**EDIT**
Well, as was pointed out, I was wrong, because the limit terms as the series goes to infinity equal -1.
Just goes to show, $\infty - \infty$ can equal anything, so avoid that form when possible.
It's really easy to make an answer that looks right, much harder to make it airtight.  Kudos to @jjagmath.

Comment: This shows the danger of manipulating divergent series. The actual answer is $2/3$

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of partial fractions since
$$\frac{n}{2n-1}=\frac{n-\frac 12+\frac 12}{2n-1}=\frac 12+\frac 1{2(2n-1)}$$
$$\frac{n+2}{2n+3}=\frac{n+\frac 32+\frac 12}{2n+3}=\frac 12+\frac 1{2(2n+3)}$$
$$\frac{n}{2n-1}-\frac{n+2}{2n+3}=\frac 1{2(2n-1)}-\frac 1{2(2n+3)}$$

Comment: This is partial fractions..

Comment: @username. These are fractions directly obtained.

Comment: Still are partial fractions, even if you found them directly

Answer (score -1):

It becomes easier if you generalise the problem: You are calculating the sum of f(n) - f(n+2), where f(n) = n / (2n-1).

The partial sums for the sum up to k are f(1)-f(3) when k=1, f(1)+f(2)-f(3)-f(4) = f(1)+f(2)-f(k+1)-f(k+2) when k=2, and from then on the partial sum is f(1)+f(2)-f(k+1)-f(k+2) for all k.

In this case, since f(k+1) and f(k+2) both converge towards 1/2, the limit is f(1)+f(2)-1 = 1+2/3-1 = 2/3. The same method will always work if f(k+1)+f(k+2) has a limit, and otherwise the sum doesn’t converge.